# Inconsistencies with Groupby in .Net-Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I'm trying to understand how `GroupBy` work properly without materializing when operating on an enumerable

I have an Entity which looks like so:

```
public class ConfigurationValue
{ 
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string KeyField {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

My query looks like so:

```
var groupQuery = context.ConfigurationValues.GroupBy(x => x.Namespace);
Func<ConfigurationValue, bool> orderFunc = y => y.Type == "Int";

//This should call Enumerable because there is no direct conversion to Queryable
var shouldCallInMemory = groupQuery.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == "Int"))
                                                 .ToArray();

var usingExplicitFunc = groupQuery.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(orderFunc)).ToArray();
```

If you look at the `IGrouping<,>` interface it only implements IEnumerable

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, 
      IEnumerable
{
    //...
}
```

My first variable which should be called in Memory because my Lambda Expression should be converted into a `Func` which means there would be no way to translate that into SQL.  Yet It generates the Proper SQL As Seen here:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[ConfigurationValueId] AS [ConfigurationValueId], 
[Limit1].[Namespace] AS [Namespace], 
[Limit1].[Key] AS [Key], 
[Limit1].[Value] AS [Value], 
[Limit1].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Limit1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
[Limit1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Limit1].[OwnerGlobalId] AS [OwnerGlobalId]
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Namespace] AS [Namespace]
    FROM [dbo].[ConfigurationValue] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent2].[ConfigurationValueId] AS [ConfigurationValueId], 
    [Extent2].[Namespace] AS [Namespace], 
    [Extent2].[Key] AS [Key], 
    [Extent2].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent2].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Extent2].[OwnerGlobalId] AS [OwnerGlobalId]
    FROM [dbo].[ConfigurationValue] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Distinct1].[Namespace] = [Extent2].[Namespace]) AND (N'Int' = [Extent2].[Type]) ) AS [Limit1]
```

Using an explicit Func I would expect then to do the same yet it generates an error:

> Unsupported overload used for query operator 'FirstOrDefault'

This is extremely confusing and inconsistent, as it's misleading to the proper behavior, and requires you to use work around when using explicit lambdas

**Edit**

`IGrouping<,>` only implements `IEnumerable`, yet when passing a lambda, it is still properly translated,  How is this working does the compiler have a special case for handling `GroupBy`?

**Edit**

I've opened an issue with Microsoft on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30403)

What appears to be happening is at the point of Select you are still creating an expression `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == "Int")).ToArray()`
the Lambda `y => y.Type == "Int"` will still be compiled as a func, but it's not actually used because the select `x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == "Int")` is actually generating an expression,

I'm speculating Expression's generated during compiled time probably don't use reflection, and have some special behavior because they are actually Lambda's.

I'm hoping a C# guru can clarify how the compiler properly handles this situation?

Comment: yeah, it appears to be translating a func, I'll reclarify

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I can use explicit expressions only if I cast using `AsQueryable` but if you use an explicit `Func` It blows up.  The implementation of this is perplexing.   I've figure out how to filter I just don't know why this behavior is happening

Comment: I think the `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == "Int"))` part is looking at the expressions within itself, rather than it asking the `IGrouping<,>` to produce sql. So the `.Select` is doing all the translation work, not the grouping. When you pass a `Func`, it can no longer translate it

Comment: That makes sense but, it weird because there is no overload for using Expressions on `IGrouping` if you want to use an explicit expression you have to cast using `.AsQueryable`, but if you want to use an func you can pass it but it will break compilation later,  `IGrouping` should Implement IQueryable, and that should be the default when chained.

Comment: Actually, I'm still a bit confused, because if the expression was reflecting into that part, It would have to still be compiled as an expression or else it would be reflecting into a function, maybe theres special handling for Lambdas in general?

Comment: Maybe the Expression is generated, and the inner lambda is compiled but thrown away since it’s not used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's *just* focus on the `shouldCallInMemory` case. So your code is:

```
var groupQuery = context.ConfigurationValues.GroupBy(x => x.Namespace);
//This should call Enumerable because there is no direct conversion to Queryable
var shouldCallInMemory = groupQuery.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == "Int"))
                                                 .ToArray();
```

Now you gave reasoning based on `IGrouping`, but that's only the type that the *inner* lambda expression uses. The *outer* lambda expression is still converted to an expression tree, *including the inner lambda expression itself*.

It's easiest to show this with a standalone example which doesn't actually query anything:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Value doesn't matter... we're interested in the type inference
        IQueryable<IGrouping<string, string>> grouping = null;

        FakeSelect(grouping, x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y == "Int"));
    }

    static void FakeSelect<TSource, TResult>(
        IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selector);
    }
}
```

The output of that is:

```
x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => (y == "Int"))
```

So the expression tree contains a method call to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` with an argument representing the predicate. The second parameter is of type `Func<string, bool>`, but we're never actually evaluating the expression tree. The point is that the expression tree retains the fact that the argument is a lambda expression, and the code within the lambda expression... which means EF (or whatever) is able to translate it into SQL.

Comment: This explaination makes sense, but the secondary case generates an Error,  What would be the recommending approach for passing an explicit `Func`? If you wanted to use an Explicit Expression you would have to call `AsQueryable` in the `Select`, but if you want to use an explicit Func this generate a compiler error, Is this a bug/flaw in Microsofts Design, shouldn't GroupBy Implement IQueryable?

Comment: @johnny5: You can't pass in an explicit `Func`, because then the expression tree doesn't have the information for what's represented in that. The point is that the expression tree needs to have *all* the information required to convert it into SQL. If you wanted to break it into stages you could probably use an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and create a `LambdaExpression` out of that, and build the outer part manually. I'm not sure I'd call it a bug in the design - hard to say for sure, really.

Comment: If you are to look at the overload for IGrouping, it shows you are operating on an Enumerable, while chaining any other linq method from an IQueryable you will still be operating on an IQueryable.   By using the Enumerable Overload, Shouldn't I expect materialization prior to the Filtering?  Isn't the only reason the expression is generating properly is because they coincidentally use DuckTyping for generating the Select expression?

Comment: @johnny5: But `GroupBy` doesn't return an `IGrouping`, it returns an `IQueryable<IGrouping>`. You're never executing an `Enumerable` method, you're just *representing* a call to that method within the expression tree passed to `Select`. I'm not sure what you mean about using duck typing for generating expressions, but it's really because everything within a lambda expression that's converted into an expression tree is contained within the expression tree - including the details of any further lambda expressions which *would* be converted into delegates.

Comment: Sorry I misworded that,  `IGrouping` in a sense is still apart of the SQL Query.  We can see this because, our Inner Lambda is being Executed on the SQL side.  If this is the case, essentially `IGrouping` continues to operate on the Query, and should implement `IQueryable`, Expression syntax is being.  The outer expression Ignores the overload for Enumerable Overload for `FirstOrDefault` and chooses the FirstOrDefault for Queryable, despite of what the compiler shows you in Visual Studio.

Comment: @johnny5: "The outer expression Ignores the overload for Enumerable Overload for FirstOrDefault and chooses the FirstOrDefault for Queryable, despite of what the compiler shows you in Visual Studio." No, it doesn't. Look at the generated expression tree, and you'll see that the part of the tree referring to the `FirstOrDefault` call refers to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault.` It's being executed in SQL because the *whole operation* is operating on an `IQueryable` with an expression tree.

Comment: I definitely agree this is all getting executed in SQL, but if the expression tree claims to be using the enumerable FirstOrDefault, I don’t understand why we shouldn’t expect the results to be filter in memory?

Comment: @johnny5: Because the "bigger" operation is done as an `IQueryable`. Just think that everything within that outer lambda expression is part of the query transformed into SQL.